# ASP.NET LoadControl Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, loadcontrol

I want a web service to load an .ascx control, load some values in it and then return the HTML content of this control. I have something like that:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void GetHTML()
{
    UserControl loader = new UserControl();
    MyCustomReport reportControl =
        (MyCustomReport)loader.LoadControl("~/The/path/to/the/.ascx");
    reportControl.DataBind();

    return "TODO";
}
```

MyCustomReport overrides `DataBind()`:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    base.DataBind();

    // etc.
}
```

The row `base.DataBind()` throws a `NullReferenceException` and the debugger says:

> Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public override void OnDataBinding() 
{ 
    base.OnDataBinding(); 

    // other stuff here ...
}
```

[`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol_members.aspx) does not have a virtual `DataBind` method but it does have a virtual `OnDataBinding` method.  I believe this is the method you mean to override.

Comment: 10x Andrew, this way it does not crash at base.OnDataBinding(); however I think this changes the meaning of the code. MyCustomReport has subcontrols, with a similar override - before, the base.DataBind(); led to their databinding, now their OnDataBinding()s don't get called.
The same control works, when put directly into an .aspx file, the problem seems to be the way I load it in the Web service, yet I cannot figure what out what is wrong exactly.